# I need a solution to a problem. I could not figure out myself how to do it

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

I was trying to solve this problem. But I could not figure out how to do it. Please help or provide a hint how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Start by showing what you have attempted so far. This is not a free homework service.

Comment: I think you didn't got my question. See what i am saying

Comment: @khalid, We understand your question? Can you show the work you have done to solve to the problem? Then we can help you.

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- you need to consider a few constraintsdue to strength.

  - compession strength
  - buckling strength

Those two will give you a mininum D, d.

Additionally you need to consider the vibrational behaviour:

- you need to calculate the sdof harmonic oscillator model. Ie what is the equivalent mass and equivalent stiffness for horizontal movement
- transmissability ratio due to base excitation. That way you'll be able to find the force induced by the vibration
- then you d need to use the force to calculate the bending stress on the base of the column. That will give you another set of D,d constraints.

Keep in  mind that the equivalent stiffness will be depended on the diameters. Therefore deepening on how you solve this problem you might need to do iterative calculations.

Comment: Thanks buddy for providing the hint